# Sentence structure: V 还 V 不来 呢

Tags: sentence-structure

I have come across this 还-based sentence structure and don't know what it implies. Here is an example:

中文：有人请你玩儿你还不去？ 这样的好事我盼还盼不来呢

英语：Somebody invited you over and you're not going?! Such a good offer, I... wouldn't imagine hoping for?

Not sure what V 还 V 不来呢 means. Also, I'm not sure if 来 belongs to the sentence structure, or if it is a separation of 盼来。 All 还 sentence structures I can find involve 还 V or 还 Adj, not a verb on both sides. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Not sure what V 还 V 不来呢 means*

盼 = wish for

还 = still

盼(不来) = wish for (and not successfully get)

> 盼还盼不来 = wished for, but still not successfully get

- To understand the role of 来, please read [result complement](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/result_complement)
- 得 and 不 are the only two potential particles that indicate 'able' or unable'

Example:

做 = to do

做到 (verb with result complement) = to do *successfully*

做得到 (verb with result complement + positive potential particle) = able to do *successfully*

做不到 (verb with result complement + negative potential particle) = unable to do *successfully*

Similarly:

盼 = wish for

盼来 = wish for (and get)

盼得来 = wish for (and able to *successfully* get)

盼不来 = wish for (and unable to *successfully* get)

- 还 means "still"

有人 = someone

请你 = invite (and treat) you to

玩儿 = play (to engage in activities that require spending of money)

你 = you

还 = still

不去? = don't go?

Comment: Ahhh, so it is a rewu

Comment: Oh, got submitted too soon! So it is a result complement - good to know! Now that you explain it, the meaning is crystal clear - thanks for your time, Tang!

Answer (score 2):

V 还 V 不来呢 can mean out of someone's mind or out of someone's ability.

"有人" = someone

"請" can translate to invite , which means someone think you are capable to do or you are a great candidate.

Under the respondent assessment(feeling), he does not think this way, or respondent think chance just wont happen on himself.

Answer (score 1):

V+还+V 不来 means that **you are unable to get/do what you really want**.

还 can be replaced by 都 in this sense.  我盼还盼不来呢=我盼都盼不来呢.

E. g.  我(想)要还要不来呢.

Answer (score 1):

In 盼还盼不来, the important grammatical part is `V 不来` wherein 不来 indicates **a [negative potential complement](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Direction_complement#Converting_to_Potential_Complement)**, and specifically **the verb V is unfulfilled**.  This is one example of many possibilities e.g. 吃不完 or 想不出来 or 站不起来 or 写不下.  E.g.:

> 为什么我**盼不来**宝宝?<sup>[[src]](http://tag.120ask.com/jingyan/8lzqu5sko0wv3l9yr8.html)</sup>
> Why, when I yearn, does no baby come? [approximate translation]

Similarly, in the given example, 盼不来 means what is being hoped for (as determined by the context) is unfulfilled.  E.g.:

> 我盼还盼不来。
> I yearn [for something determined by context], still my yearning is unfulfilled.

Note that [还](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%BF%98) ("still") could be replaced by [也](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%B9%9F) (as in e.g. 盼也盼不来) or [都](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%83%BD) (as in e.g. 盼都盼不来; as [dan mentions](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/38837/8099)) without changing the meaning (and similar things happen in [other](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22in_addition%22_with_%22lingwai%22) [grammar](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Many_types_of_%22not_only..._but_also...%22) [structures](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22except%22_and_%22in_addition%22_with_%22chule%E2%80%A6_yiwai%22)).  The 呢 in the original sentence basically [expresses surprise](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Advanced_uses_of_%22hai%22#Expressing_a_Strong_Tone_of_Surprise), and it's not so important (arguably more related to a person's speaking style, and dependent on context).

I don't think `V 还 V 不来` can be considered a specific grammar structure.  Negative potential complements can arise in a lot of ways:

> **跳舞还跳不赢**这位大爷.<sup>[[src]](https://v.qq.com/x/page/x0549zns9o7.html)</sup>
> [I] dance, [but] still don't beat this show-off.
>
> 为什么有些人天天**吃饺子还吃不够**?<sup>[[src]](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1647176027391787159&wfr=spider&for=pc)</sup>
> Why do some people eat dumplings everyday, [but] still have not eaten enough?
>
> 为什么**戴眼镜还看不清**?<sup>[[src]](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1950700206199922908.html)</sup>
> Why, [despite] wearing glasses, [I] still cannot see clearly?
>
> 以前我也很烦妈妈的碎碎念，现在**想听也听不到**了.<sup>[[src]](https://www.weibo.com/1256590012/FAflg5ov4?type=comment)</sup>
> Before I was annoyed at [my] mother's nagging, [but] now I want to hear, [but] still cannot hear.
>
> 怎么**喝都喝不醉**呢?
> How to drink and still not get drunk?